# How can I optimize my code by regrouping shared styles between cards?

Tags: html, css

This is my css and my html below, I want to apply some rules to all the cards, and change only the color of the top by selecting each card. But I didn't find how to select multiple class at the the same time. I don't know if you can understand what I said but for me my code is very bad and I want to improve it.

```css
.card-supervisor {
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}

.card-team-builder {
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(0, 78%, 62%);
}

.card-karma {
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(34, 97%, 64%);
}

.card-calculator {
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(212, 86%, 64%);
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
        <div class="card-supervisor">
          <h1 class="card-title">Supervisor</h1>
          <p class="card-paragraph">Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks</p>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/icon-supervisor.svg">
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card-team-builder">
          <h1 class="card-title">Team Builder</h1>
          <p class="card-paragraph">Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project</p>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/icon-team-builder.svg">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card-karma">
          <h1 class="card-title">Karma</h1>
          <p class="card-paragraph">Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality</p>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/icon-karma.svg">
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card-calculator">
          <h1 class="card-title">Calculator</h1>
          <p class="card-paragraph">Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates</p>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/icon-calculator.svg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `card` class that you add to all cards, add the shared styles on it like so:

```css
.card{
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}
.card-supervisor {
    border-color:hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}

.card-team-builder {
    border-color: hsl(0, 78%, 62%);
}

.card-karma {
   border-color: hsl(34, 97%, 64%);
}

.card-calculator {
   border-color:hsl(212, 86%, 64%);
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
        <div class="card card-supervisor">
          <h1 class="card-title">Supervisor</h1>
          <p class="card-paragraph">Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks</p>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/icon-supervisor.svg">
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card card-team-builder">
          <h1 class="card-title">Team Builder</h1>
          <p class="card-paragraph">Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project</p>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/icon-team-builder.svg">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card card-karma">
          <h1 class="card-title">Karma</h1>
          <p class="card-paragraph">Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality</p>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/icon-karma.svg">
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card card-calculator">
          <h1 class="card-title">Calculator</h1>
          <p class="card-paragraph">Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates</p>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/icon-calculator.svg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Definitly better code !

Answer (score 1):

Use a selector including all classes for the common properties (using commas to list them all) and after that separate rules for the color

```
.card-supervisor, .card-team-builder, .card-karma, .card-calculator {
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}

.card-supervisor {
  background: blue;
}
.card-team-builder {
  background: red;
}
.card-karma {
  background: yellow;
}
.card-calculator {
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select multiple classes separated by commas

```css
.card-supervisor,
.card-team-builder,
.card-karma,
.card-calculator {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem 0.5rem #dedede;
}
.card-supervisor {
  border-top: 0.5rem solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}

.card-team-builder {
  border-top: 0.5rem solid hsl(0, 78%, 62%);
}

.card-karma {
  border-top: 0.5rem solid hsl(34, 97%, 64%);
}

.card-calculator {
  border-top: 0.5rem solid hsl(212, 86%, 64%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As all card have most of their properties to be the same you can create a global `.card` class and create class modifier for each kind of card you have

You can learn more about

1. [OOCSS](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/oocss) **Object Oriented CSS**
2. [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/)
3. [BEM](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) **Block, Element, Modifier**

```css
.card {
      border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
}

.card-supervisor {
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}

.card-team-builder {
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(0, 78%, 62%);
}

.card-karma {
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(34, 97%, 64%);
}

.card-calculator {
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(212, 86%, 64%);
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <div class="card card-supervisor">
    <h1 class="card-title">Supervisor</h1>
    <p class="card-paragraph">Monitors activity to identify project roadblocks</p>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="images/icon-supervisor.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-team-builder">
    <h1 class="card-title">Team Builder</h1>
    <p class="card-paragraph">Scans our talent network to create the optimal team for your project</p>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="images/icon-team-builder.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-karma">
    <h1 class="card-title">Karma</h1>
    <p class="card-paragraph">Regularly evaluates our talent to ensure quality</p>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="images/icon-karma.svg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-calculator">
    <h1 class="card-title">Calculator</h1>
    <p class="card-paragraph">Uses data from past projects to provide better delivery estimates</p>
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="images/icon-calculator.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add common set of css codes to no.of classes, add them by separating with commas as below.

```
.card-supervisor, .card-team-builder, .card-karma, .card-calculator {
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
}
```

But always remember you can add more than one class to a html element. So the best practice is adding the common codes with a one common class and the unique css with another class or id like below

```
<div class="card-item card-supervisor">
```

css

```
.card-list{
    border-radius: .5rem;
    padding: 2.5rem 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem .5rem #dedede;
}
.card-supervisor {
    border-top: .5rem solid hsl(180, 62%, 55%);
}
```

Comment: Some of the grouping removed question's provided example

Comment: Yes, I only added a single div that should be modified to give an idea.